# What would a specific example of a simple async/await function be expressed as Promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I'm trying to understand the relationship between `async`/`await` and `Promise`s in TypeScript and have gotten myself a but too confused, I think.

Im particular, I'm trying to understand how the `async`/`await` version of an example function,  `downloadFileAA`, defined below maps to an implementation that uses `Promise`s instead. What is going in behind the scenes with `Promise`s? Obviously neither of my `Promise` versions are satisfactory or entirely capture what's going on in the `async`/`await` version (`downloadFilePromise` never reports success or failure, and  `downloadFilePromise2` requires some weird redundancy: `result.then()` in the argument to `resolve` to pass type checking), but I'm not certain why.

What would a `Promise`-based version of `downloadFileAA` look like? Is there a reason to prefer it (or not) over the `async`/`await` version?

```js
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'

const callback = ( downloadProgress ) => {
    const progress = downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten / downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite
    console.log(
        `${Number( progress )
            .toLocaleString( undefined, { style: 'percent', minimumFractionDigits: 0 } )
            .padStart( 5, ' ' )} of ${downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite} bytes`
    )
}

const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
    'http://...',
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'somebigfile',
    {},
    callback
)

const downloadFileAA = async () => {
    try {
        console.log( 'Starting download (with async/await)... ' )
        const result = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync()
        console.log( result ? `Finished downloading to ${result.uri}` : 'Undefined result?'  )
    } catch ( e ) {
        console.error( `Failed download: ${e.message}` )
    }
}

const downloadFilePromise = () => {
        console.log( 'Starting download (with Promise)... ' )
        new Promise<FileSystem.FileSystemDownloadResult>(  ( resolve, reject ) =>
            downloadResumable.downloadAsync()
         )
            .then( ( result ) => console.log( `Finished downloading to ${result.uri}` ) )
            .catch( ( reason ) => console.error( `Failed download: ${reason}` ) )
}

const downloadFilePromise2 = () => {
        console.log( 'Starting download (with Promise Two)... ' )
        new Promise<FileSystem.FileSystemDownloadResult>(  ( resolve, reject ) => {
            const result = downloadResumable.downloadAsync()
            result  ? resolve( result.then() ) : reject( result )
        } )
            .then( ( result ) => console.log( `Finished downloading to ${result.uri}` ) )
            .catch( ( reason ) => console.error( `Failed download: ${reason}` ) )
}
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-promise-and-async-await-in-node-js/#:~:text=Promise%20is%20an%20object%20representing,the%20code%20execute%20more%20synchronously.

Comment: @vanowm Yes, lol, that's exactly what got me started trying to translate from async/await to Promises, but as you can see I didn't get very far.

Comment: `async`/`await` is not syntactic sugar for `new Promise`, but only for `.then(…)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `downloadAsync` returns a Promise and that `console.log` doesn't throw, this

```
const downloadFileAA = async () => {
    try {
        console.log( 'Starting download (with async/await)... ' )
        const result = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync()
        console.log( result ? `Finished downloading to ${result.uri}` : 'Undefined result?'  )
    } catch ( e ) {
        console.error( `Failed download: ${e.message}` )
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
const downloadFileAA = () => {
    console.log('Starting download (with async/await)... ')
    return downloadResumable.downloadAsync()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result ? `Finished downloading to ${result.uri}` : 'Undefined result?')
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(`Failed download: ${e.message}`);
        });
};
```

What `await` does is it replaces `.then`. It doesn't replace Promises - both `.then` and `await` require a Promise (to be used sensibly, at least).

Your `downloadFilePromise` function is broken because it constructs a Promise that, by definition, never resolves - you must call the `resolve` or `reject` argument in order for the constructed Promise to resolve. But since it looks like `downloadAsync` *already* returns a Promise, constructing another Promise to surround it [doesn't make any sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)  - just use the Promise you have instead of making a new one.

> Is there a reason to prefer it (or not) over the async/await version?

It's purely a stylistic choice. IMO `await` shines best when there are multiple values that need to be waited for (serially), but otherwise either work just fine (as long as they're implemented properly, of course).

Comment: As an addendum, I would say the caveat "as long as they're implemented properly" is an important one. One of the main strengths of async-await is that control flow is very easy to visualise, whereas with `.then()` chains, it's easy to overlook a chain with no catcher etc. So while yes, both can be used to write equivalent code, in my personal opinion async-await makes mistakes easier to spot. And since we all make mistakes when writing code, that's a very good thing.

Comment: You should return `downloadResumable.downloadAsync` in the second example otherwise this can't be awaited.

Comment: @lawrence-witt In `downloadFilePromise`? How does that fix it?